# pd.scatter_matrixでのエラー

Tags: python

下のようなエラーが出ます。
これはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import mglearn
from IPython.display import display
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'], random_state=0)

#x_trainのデータからDataFrameを作る、
#iris_dataset.feature_namesの文字列を使ってカラムに名前を付ける。
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train,            
columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
#データフレームからscatter matrixを作成し、y_trainに従って色をつける。

grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize(15, 15),          
marker='o',hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

```
File "<ipython-input-45-5ef480aab756>", line 6
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize(15, 15),     
marker='o',                                                  ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

参照：pythonではじめる機械学習

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.scatter_matrix()` の引数の、`figsize(15, 15)` の部分を `figsize=(15, 15)`
 に修正してください。

Comment: 回答あいがとうございます。修正したらエラーが消えました！が/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: FutureWarning: pandas.scatter_matrix is deprecated. Use pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix insteadという出力になりました。グラフが本当なら出力されるはずなんですがこれはなぜだと思われますか？

Comment: `pd.scatter_matrix()` は非推奨APIなので `pd.plotting.scatter_matrix()`を使ってくださいと *警告* しているだけですので、そのように書き換えると*警告*は消えると思います。
グラフが表示されないのは単に `%matplotlib inline` を行っていない（jupyter上で実行している場合）、もしくは ``plt.show()`` を行っていない（jupyterを使用していない場合）が原因ではないでしょうか